# Unable to build GLFW with CMake errors

Tags: c, cmake, glfw

I downloaded the latest GLFW source (3.1.1) from its site, uncompressed it to the desktop, and tried to build it with `cmake`. Some dependency errors popped up, but was quickly fixed. Until I got stuck on this one:

```
alex@alex-AMD:~/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1$ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 3.6.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so
-- Looking for XOpenDisplay in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXext.so - found
-- Looking for gethostbyname
-- Looking for gethostbyname - found
-- Looking for connect
-- Looking for connect - found
-- Looking for remove
-- Looking for remove - found
-- Looking for shmat
-- Looking for shmat - found
-- Found X11: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so
-- Found OpenGL: /usr/lib/libGL.so  
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Found Doxygen: /usr/bin/doxygen (found version "1.8.6") 
-- Using X11 for window creation
-- Using GLX for context creation
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddress
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddress - found
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressARB
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressARB - found
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressEXT
-- Looking for glXGetProcAddressEXT - not found
CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)
    linked by target "boing" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "gears" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "heightmap" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "particles" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "simple" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "splitview" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples
    linked by target "wave" in directory /home/alex/Desktop/glfw-3.1.1/examples

-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I'm totally lost as to what this means, and how to proceed

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, with proprietary AMD Radeon 7950 drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the error outputs was `Looking for glXGetProcAddressEXT - not found`, and the log files indicated that there was a linking error with libGL.

I then tried running `apt-get install glfw` to print out the list of dependencies. Even though it was an older version in `apt-get`, it still listed some dependencies that had to be installed.

GLFW compiled after installing `libglu1-mesa-dev` and `libgl1-mesa-dev`

The last error message `CMake Error: The following variables are used in this project, but they are set to NOTFOUND.
Please set them or make sure they are set and tested correctly in the CMake files:
OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY (ADVANCED)` was the one that threw me off. I thought it was a problem with paths and environment variables